# Auto-indexing project source code after "git pull" in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, version-control

After getting updates with `git pull` I started to test some class (I didn't change it) and got `NullPointerException` in some unexpected place. I've messed some time trying to realize the issue with debug, but only after rebuilding project Idea started indexing and debug started showing the problem in right place.

So, the question - is there any possibility to adjust Intellij Idea to index source code after VCS update to avoid such a "trap"?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA does automatically index source code after any external changes, including VCS updates. It's hard to see what exactly happened in your situation, but this is not something that normally happens, and there are no settings to control this.

Comment: Agree with you - it was strange, but I saw such a behaviour, in case you make changes manually and start to debug, debugger can point to unexpected line, even to empty line. But as I mentioned I didn't make any changes except new test class.